# Calling cmd.exe and writing inside a command/exe without executing the instruction

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have to options to solve my problem:

1. Open a cmd with a route written inside (`myroute\iwanttocall.exe`) without executing so the user can pass the .exe 2 argument, e.g.: `iwanttocall.exe argument1 argument2`
2. Open a clean cmd in the location myroute so the user can call `iwanttocall.exe` and the 2 arguments.

How can I do this?

I've tried with start `cmd.exe /C` and `/K "iwanttocall.exe"` but that will just execute the command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SET /P` to prompt a user for input.

```
SET /P myArgs=Enter your parameters:
myroute\iwanttocall.exe %myArgs%
```